# Scrapy + phantomjs + selenium raise NotImplementedError

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape a page with some javascript elements, I've made this, which has a part to pass the 302  (that I tested and it works fine):

```
class bllanguage(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
    name = "bllanguage"
    allowed_domains = ["http://explore.com/"]
    start_urls = [
    'http://explore.com/this-other-url'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
            driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')


    def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            r = scrapy.Request(url = u, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse)
            r.meta['dont_redirect'] = True
            yield r

        def parse(self, response):
                driver.get(response.url)
                print response.url
```

It gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line
>   577, in _runCallbacks
>           current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>         File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py", line 76, in parse
>           raise NotImplementedError
>       NotImplementedError

I can't understand what I'm making wrong, if somebody could gives me an hint, it will be great.

EDIT:
As @paul trmbrth said, I had to put "def parse" in the same indentation of "def start_requests". But now I have this:

> line 30, in parse
>       driver.get(response.url)
>   NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined

But I defined it in def **_ init _**: why that?

Comment: In the code you pasted, `parse` is defined inside the `start_requests` block. Your `parse` method must be at the same indentation level as `start_requests` and `__init__`

Comment: Thanks! It works, but now it gives me another error: line 30, in parse  driver.get(response.url) NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined.
I'll edit right away.

Comment: in `__init__()`, use `self.driver = ` instead of `driver = ` and in `parse()`, use `self.driver`, otherwise, `driver` is only local to `__init__()` and thrown away when returning and therefore not available in `parse()`